# PPA: How to force an older lib version from PPA for building?

Tags: ppa, packaging, qbittorrent

I maintain this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~qbittorrent-team/+archive/ubuntu/qbittorrent-stable

I want to build qbittorrent against the provided(in the PPA) libtorrent version. This is because we don't officially support libtorrent 1.1.x for stable releases.

The problem is that yakkety/zesty have the newer 1.1.1 version in their repos which supersedes my 1.0.11 PPA version. I have put in the `control` file this:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7.4.12),
               libtorrent-rasterbar-dev (>= 1.0.7),
               libtorrent-rasterbar-dev (<< 1.1.0),
               libboost-dev,
               libboost-system-dev,
               qtbase5-dev (>= 5.2.0),
               qttools5-dev-tools
```

But it still fails. I admit I am not very good with debian packaging. Is there any way to make it select the PPA version?

Comment: There is no way to do that. You can specify different versioning like `1.0+{revno/commit}+{time}~ppa` under recipe build.....Other option is use `1.0.11.is.1.1.1-0ubuntu4` which they used for [nautilus](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu4)....but it doesn't work properly under ppa and against debian policy for version-scheme.

Comment: I just checked the failed build log in that stable ppa, There is no `libtorrent-rasterbar-dev (<< 1.1.0)` condition , i saw only (>= 1.0.7), did I miss something?